# Using Azure CLI v2 ML-extension in DevOps pipeline ("az" command)

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, mlops

I am trying to install "ml" extension for Azure CLI (`az extension add -n ml -y --debug`) in an Azure DevOps pipeline and getting an error because the extension is incompatible with that az version included into the "mcr.microsoft.com/mlops/python:latest" image (that is used by the pipeline runner):

```
Skipping 'ml-2.0.0a1-py3-none-any.whl' as not compatible with this version of the CLI.
```

So I apparently need to update the az command, but how that can be done in the pipeline code? "az upgrade" did not work:

```
az: 'upgrade' is not in the 'az' command group
```

Or alternatively, is there an mlops image that would have the new version of az command already included?

Comment: Did you try `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli` container and adding ml there? The documentation states you should install it az cli manually since it's too old.  Basically either install new az or Python on az container

Comment: I changed the image to mcr.microsoft.com/azure-dev-cli-apps:latest which seems to have the latest az command. However, it is using python2.7 as the default python, so I changed my python calls into python3. Then, I needed to "pip3 install azureml", but my code is still complaining "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azureml.core'". I don't know what is wrong with that, since the azureml installation succeeds. Any ideas?

Comment: Answering to myself. It looks like one must install the parts of the azureml separately, so I needed to "pip3 install azureml-core" and also azureml-pipeline to get my code running.

Comment: if you could change the title to be more appropriate and then add an answer that would help feature people that might want to do the same setup (or help yourself in the future when you want to remember what you did)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @misha130 suggested, changing the default container image `mcr.microsoft.com/mlops:latest` defined in the Azure DevOps pipeline into another one having a more recent Azure CLI (az) solved the problem:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: my-mlops
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-dev-cli-apps:latest
```

However, that image did not have azureml Python components pre-installed, so I also needed to add these installation commands into the pipeline:

```
  pip3 install azureml
  pip3 install azureml-core
  pip3 install azureml-pipeline
```

After that, I was able to run `az ml` commands (after `az extension add -n ml -y`) and also run python3 code with azureml imports from my Azure DevOps pipeline.

Comment: Had the same issue. Looks like "az extension add -n ml" does not check or warn if the python libs are missing. And just passes :( Installing needed packages via pip3 helped me out.

`pip3 install azureml`

  `pip3 install azureml-core`

  `pip3 install azureml-pipeline
`